# Clang generates errors when I try to use AVX features

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm on Windows 10, with Clang version 5 (recently installed). When I compile the following

```
#define __AVX__
#define __AVX2__
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(void) {
    __m256i a, b, result;
    result = _mm256_add_epi64(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: always_inline function '_mm256_add_epi64' requires target 
 feature 'avx2', but would be inlined into function 'main' that is 
 compiled without support for 'avx2'
    result = _mm256_add_epi64(a, b);
             ^
```

MSVC compiles it just fine. What compiler option do I need to use in order to get Clang to compile this? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: `-Ctarget-features=`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are native compiling (host and target being the same machine so, *not* cross-compilation), then consider passing `-march=native` to `clang`

See also the [user manual of the Clang compiler](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

Notice that the Clang compiler is [open source](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). You are allowed to download its source code and improve it.

Comment: This works for clang, but clang-cl does not accept that flag. Is there an equivalent for clang-cl?

Comment: @brothir Usually all clang-specific options can be passed even to clang-cl by prepending `-Xclang`, for example `-Xclang -march=native`.