# How to fix Clion error for supporting avx

Tags: c++, clang, clion, avx

I am using Clion in Mac to write C++ code with the Clang compiler. I know that my CPU supports AVX1.0. However, I think there is a problem with compiling `AVX` stuff in this simple code. The error is:

```
always_inline function '_mm256_set_ps' requires target feature 'avx', but would be inlined into function 'main' that is compiled without support for 'avx'
```

and the code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

    /* Initialize the two argument vectors */
    __m256 evens = _mm256_set_ps(2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0);
    __m256 odds = _mm256_set_ps(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0);

    /* Compute the difference between the two vectors */
    __m256 result = _mm256_sub_ps(evens, odds);

    /* Display the elements of the result vector */
    auto* f = (float*)&result;
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n",
           f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

should I change something in Clion?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Clang generates errors when I try to use AVX features](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47207637) / [How to compile program with \_mm\_clflushopt function? error: inlining failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54409300)  except for the cmake syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. Add it in your Cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native")
```

Now, it works properly.